# Symfony Prod environment gives a 500 internal server erro

Tags: symfony-1.4, development-environment, production-environment

My project works just fine in it's dev environment. However, when I attempt to access the prod version that is without the *_dev.php url prefixes, I get redirected to the login page (as it should) and upon logging in it screams a 500 internal server error.

This is true for both the prod site and my dev machine. What's going wrong here?

Comment: What logs says? Do you perform a `clear-cache`? Have you enable log for the prod env to see more information?

Comment: The error should be written in apache error log. Check that file.

Answer (score 11):

Clear cache and set permission 777 to prod folder.

Command to clear cache: `php bin/console cache:clear`
Command to full permission: `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/cache/prod`

This should work!

Comment: You don't need 777 on /var/cache/prod, 775 is enough

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I just removed the cache folder: rm -rf var/cache, and it worked without changing the permissions

Answer (score 0):

I add a **500 error** when deploying in production, but I did not get it when in **dev environment**. Nothing was valuable in the logs, and after trying everythong with permissions and cache, it seems that it was a perfect silent PHP crash.

The issue came from an **EasyAdmin AssociationField** that was retreiving too many items from the collection. That is why I saw this in prod but not in dev.
After applying a custom QueryBuilder, the error 500 disappeared.

Hope it can help, the difference between prod and dev is often permissions, but it can also be the **database**.